# Changing XML values in Android/Java

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to take an XML file as input which contains the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes'>
<map>
    <int name="count" value="10" />
</map>
```

and, read and change the **value** from 10 to any other integer value.

How can I do this in Android/Java. I'm new to Android and Java and all the tutorials available on the internet are way too complicated.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the value by matching the pattern and replacing the string as like below,

```
String xmlString = "<int name=\"count\" value=\"10\" />";
int newValue = 100;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(<int name=\"count\" value=\")([0-9]{0,})(\" />)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(xmlString);

while (matcher.find()) {
    String match = matcher.group(2);
    xmlString = xmlString.replace(match, String.valueOf(newValue));
}

System.out.println(xmlString);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find your answer [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html). It is like parsing json. You can cast your string(from file) to object and do anything with parameters

Comment: I mentioned "way too complicated" keeping your link in mind. I asked here because I want a simple solution.